# How to retrieve/provide a CSRF token to/from Django as an API

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, reactjs, django-csrf

I'm working on a project that uses the Django REST Framework as a backend (let's say at `api.somecompany.com` but has a React.js frontend (at `www.somecompany.com`) not served by Django that makes AJAX requests.

I can't, therefore, use Django's traditional method of having the template include the CSRF token like this `<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}`

I can make a request to Django REST Framework's `api-auth\login\` url, which will return this header:
`Set-Cookie:csrftoken=tjQfRZXWW4GtnWfe5fhTYor7uWnAYqhz; expires=Mon, 01-Aug-2016 16:32:10 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/` - but I can't then retrieve this cookie to send back with my AJAX requests with `X-CSRFToken` (my understanding is of the separate subdomain), and it doesn't seem to be included automatically.

Here's my relevant code:

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});
```

As the page loads I call this to make sure I have a token:

```
$.ajax(loginUrl, { method: "OPTIONS", async: false })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR)
        app.csrftoken@ = $.cookie("csrftoken")
        console.log($.cookie("csrftoken"))
        console.log(app.csrftoken)
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR)
    });
```

This isn't exactly clean but I haven't proven the concept to myself yet.

What is the 'correct' way of authenticating / protecting against CSRF when the frontend and backend are on different ports/domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, as a matter of fact, make this work with CSRF protection, using a whitelist of allowed request origins.

To make this work, you're going to have to use `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing` (CORS). To achieve this, I'd recommend creating a middleware class that sets up your cross-sharing credentials. There's a [great gist](https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/1369619) that outlines how to use some of the build in cross origin HTTP request headers. You can, if you want, insert the CSRF token via middleware in this way, by changing the origin reference values for the request.

The [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) app does this for you. You can see how they've negotiated the CSRF tokens in [their middleware file](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/blob/1e7bf86310e54cf2520c1b197d4e54bf80004df3/corsheaders/middleware.py), if you're interested.

Refer to the [Django REST CORS Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/) for more on this (they recommend using django-cors-headers).

If you're still having difficulties, try:

1. setting the [`crossDomain`](http://%20api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) parameter of your AJAX request to `True`. Sometimes, jQuery won't process the request if this isn't specified.
2. if you're still not receiving a token header in the request at all, try appending the [`ensure_csrf_cookie()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator around your view method. Occasionally, when there's no `{% csrf_token %}` template tag on the page (if you're not rendering a form), Django won't include the token in the request at all.

Comment: I think I already have that covered - my request isn't failing for CORS reasons. My problem as far as I can tell is that my first request (the `OPTIONS` one) is not setting the `csrftoken` cookie, so I can't read it to add as a header, or have it automatically sent with a subsequent request. Making a request directly (not using AJAX) sets the cookie properly. Is there something barring the cookie from being set?

Comment: If that is the case, I can think of two other things that might be going wrong: first, make sure you set the `crossDomain` parameter of the AJAX request to `True` as described in api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax. 

It's also likely that, if you're not including a CSRF template tag on the page you're rendering (i.e. the page has no form), Django might not be including the token in the header by default. You can use the `ensure_csrf_cookie(view)` decorator around your view to force that (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie)